# Array.Fill() method in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to translate a Java program to C#. In the Java program there is a line `Arrays.fill(used, false);`. When googled it, there is Array.Fill<>() in C#. But I am getting an error saying Array does not contain definition for Fill(). Does anybody know how to fix this?

My project is using .NET Framework 4.8.1. I am wondering why I cannot use Array.Fill() function documented in MSDN in my installation of Visual Studio.

My code is using the namespaces 'System', 'System.Collections.Generic', and 'System.Text'.

I have googled it and found one solution as adding 'System.Runtime.dll'. But I cannot find the file in 'ReferenceAssemblies' folder. I have downloaded and installed the .NET Framework from the website directly as well as tried repairing Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method [is available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.fill?view=net-8.0) in:

- .NET: Core 2.0, Core 2.1, Core 2.2, Core 3.0, Core 3.1, 5, 6, 7, 8
- .NET Standard: 2.1

Check that your app targets one of above (not earlier .NET Framework 3.5/4.5 etc).

Comment: The app is targeting .NET Framework 4.8.1.

Comment: @thomarjos that means you can't use `Array.Fill` and should use the alternative from the dupe.

Comment: @GuruStron But why is that? Isn't it part of the .NET Framework?

Comment: @thomarjos no. It is part of .NET (Core). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72240581/2501279)

Comment: @GuruStron Thank you. That actually fixed it. I didn't which .NET I was supposed to use. I usually use .NET Framework project templates. It was not even mentioned in MSDN. You should write it as a solution so I can mark it.

Comment: @thomarjos Was glad to help! Accept this answer. It is pretty much saying the same - upgrade to .NET (Core). And upvote the answer I've linked)