# BC41997 Referenced assembly 'Autodesk.Forge, Version=1.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have a strong name. 1 Active

Tags: autodesk-forge

I get the error. BC41997    Referenced assembly 'Autodesk.Forge, Version=1.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have a strong name.

Error on compile & run

.net framework 4.8
Installed Autodesk.Forge 1.9.7.

Any ideas are appreciated

Comment: Could you try to reinstall `Autodesk.Forge` from nuget? I cannot reproduce this issue. Or could you consider providing a sample project demonstrating this issue for test?

Comment: The issue goes away if I post sign the app. However the new problem I am facing is the dependencies. The latest version of Autodesk.Forge.dll has a dependency of RestSharp >= 108.0.1. However that is not compatible with .net framework 4.8.

Comment: That seems not to be a problem from my side. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Hi Eason, thank you for your help. In order to use the latest version of Autodesk.Forge.dll, I also need to add it's dependancies, however when I look at the dependancies of RestSharp 108.0.1. .net4.8 is not listed. I also read this artical https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1832.

Comment: I don't think that is a problem since .NET standard 2.0 is backward compatible with .net framework 4.8, as I know. Please take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/63588186

Comment: Oh I didn't know that, thank you for your help, though I need to re-look at weather  Autodesk.Forge is suitable. It seems that get hubs requires a 3 legged token and that is unsuitable for my application.

Comment: Is your hub a BIM360 or ACC hub? If yes, you can use 2-legged access token.

Comment: Hi Eason, thank you so much, I feel I'm getting very close, but when I run the command I get back to the original error "Could not load file or assembly 'Autodesk.forge, version=1.9.7.0'" I have copied all the dll files from bin to the same location as the command dll. I've tried reinstalling Autodesk.Forge from nuget.

Comment: So after upgrading from Autodesk.forge, version=1.9.0.0 to Autodesk.forge, version=1.9.7.0 I'm now getting a visual studio warning that I need system.net.http 5.0.0, however there is no NuGet for this version?

Comment: I also have a Reference to RestSharp which requres 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0'